# How to test HQL without redeploy all the project?

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I got a problem that consumes a lot of time during the development i have to test somes HQL that i put in DAO, but i had to recompile all the project in eclipse and put in tomcat that takes something like 40-60seconds just to start again and if something goes wrong... again had to redeploy...

So, there is a way to test a HQL without recompile everything? like i tried the hibernate tools plugin but i don't see how to do it with annotations (the project is all with annotations, don't make use of hbm files...)

Thanks

Comment: Running from main method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a breakpoint where you need, debug in 'Display' window and write your any HQL queries in runtime.

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdisplay%2Fref-display_view.htm

Maybe helps.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are accessing your DAO through a service I would do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  AbstractApplicationContext factory = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");

  YourService yourservice = (YourService)factory.getBean("YourService");
  YourObject obj = new YourObject("data1", "data2");
  yourservice.save(obj);
  YourObject foundobj = yourservice.load(1); // or yourservice.findObjectByLabel("label")
  System.out.print(foundobj);

}
```

Or write a junit test. http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/simple-spring-transactional-junit4-test-code-example.html

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the debug option as mentioned by Vaelyr for a punctual need. 
If you require stronger assertions I would rather write some tests for the DAO as tshenolo proposed.

But if you have some time and want a nice toy to play with I would create a console page that let you interact with your application.

For that I'll use a groovy (or another script language) interpreter. If you provide the DAO or any other relevant objects to your interpreter context, then you'll have a console to perform all kind of experimentation without to re-compile anything.

You'll be able to run arbitrary code within your app !

For an example with groovy you can have a look here: [Embedding Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy) and more precisely here: [Embedding a Groovy Console in a Java Server Application](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+a+Groovy+Console+in+a+Java+Server+Application)

If you don't want to use groovy, you can also have fun with beanshell (pure java) or a rhino (javascript) or any other script language supported by the JVM.

Beware that having this kind of console is a backdoor to your app and that you should not release it as a part of your application.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in the past to test HQL is write a limited set of integration tests using an in memory db like [Hypersonic](http://hsqldb.org/) and the [Spring JUnit test extensions](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html).  [This post](http://www.cybersnippet.nl/easy-integration-testing-of-hql-with-an-in-memory-database) describes how this can be done using dbunit.  You can also just brute force the data using batch JDBC operations in your setup and tear down.

Cautionary notes: I would not add these test to your suite of unit tests as the data setup and tear down can take more time than a typical unit test.  These are really integration tests used to add you in development and debugging of your HQL only.  I wouldn't bother testing CRUD operations using these types of tests as then you're just integration testing your ORM framework which should have already been done.